# Why does my CImg<float> have negative width and height?

Tags: c++, size, dimension, cimg, negative-integer

```
CImg<float>* img = NULL;
bool loaded;

while ( !loaded )
{
    loaded = true;
    try
    {
        img = &CImg<float>( filename );
    }
    catch ( CImgException )
    {
        loaded = false;
        fprintf( stdout, "ERROR: could not load %smap file.\n", mapname );
    }
}
```

When I enter a valid image filename that CImg is able to find and read,  `img.width()` and `img.height()` both return `-858993460`. According to the [documentation](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html), `img.width()`'s return type is `int`, but the value if fetches is `img._width`, an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Is this your real code? You can't take the address of a temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GManNickG mentioned in the comment, at line `img = &CImg<float>( filename );` temporary object of type `CImg<float>` created and you stores it's address into `img` variable. This temporary object is only valid inside the block:

```
try
{
  img = &CImg<float>( filename );
}
```

It's destructed when execution leaves this scope and you've got invalid pointer with some random content (e.g. `-858993460` in `_width` field).

Comment: If I use `new` it will be allocated on the heap, is there a way to initialize an object instance and have it belong to (for example) the scope from which this method was called? None of primers on pointers that I've followed have touched on this.

Comment: @ophilbinbriscoe `CImg<T>` class has [copy constructor](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#aff97beaa34b9061351711dcdaed85c58) and [`move_to`](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a09aeb03ffe6512209f64b92fbef9574c) method. You can declare `img` as `CImg<float> img;` and simply assign `img = CImg<float>( filename );`